# GraphQL Filtered Query Returning Data to network, but getting an error afterwards

Tags: graphql, apollo, keystonejs

I've got a query that uses a `where` filter to grab only the user-created fundraisers. The query is below:

```
export const MY_FUNDRAISERS_QUERY = gql`
  query MY_FUNDRAISERS_QUERY($skip: Int = 0, $first: Int) {
    allFundraisers(
      first: $first
      skip: $skip
      sortBy: dateCreated_ASC
      where: { owner: { id: "63573546187cc1edfb4f7d1c" } }
    ) {
      id
      name
      amount
      description
      goal
      dateCreated
      photo {
        image {
          publicUrlTransformed
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

The data is returning in the network, but I'm getting this error from Apollo:

```
Error: Can't find field 'id' on object false
Can't find field 'name' on object false
Can't find field 'amount' on object false
Can't find field 'description' on object false
Can't find field 'goal' on object false
Can't find field 'dateCreated' on object false
Can't find field 'photo' on object false
    at new ApolloError (index.js:37:28)
    at ObservableQuery.getCurrentResult (ObservableQuery.js:124:32)
    at QueryData.getExecuteResult (QueryData.js:218:56)
    at QueryData.execute (QueryData.js:52:51)
    at eval (useBaseQuery.js:41:151)
    at useDeepMemo (useDeepMemo.js:11:42)
    at useBaseQuery (useBaseQuery.js:41:85)
    at useQuery (useQuery.js:6:87)
    at Fundraisers (Fundraisers.js:61:111)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:18)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:20)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:16)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23935:14)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22771:12)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22702:5)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22665:7)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22288:18)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js:11327:26)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:12)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:10)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322:9)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309:3)
    at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:21888:9)
    at dispatchAction (react-dom.development.js:16139:5)
    at eval (useBaseQuery.js:27:119)
```

The query works in my GraphQL playground as well, but only returns undefined because of the above error.

I have a dozen other queries and mutations, all of which work fine. I have a feeling it's something to do with the 'where' filter, but I'm really not sure.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: This looks like Keystone v5 (Keystone Classic), is that correct?

Comment: It's Keystone next, so I think it's v6

Comment: Yeah, Keystone Next became v6. The "next" packages are pretty outdated though – they were released as a "preview" before several of the APIs were formalised or documented, specifically not for production use, and deprecated over a year ago. Getting any support for outdated versions like this is unlikely. Better to upgrade to the latest version and see if there's still an issue.